# How to use fetch in Zapier?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api, zapier

I'm pretty much a noob with javascript and was wondering why zapier is returning:

"If you are doing async (with fetch library) you need to use a callback!"

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
    fetch('https://api.trello.com/1/boards/?name={name}&key=APIKey&token=APIToken', {
  method: 'POST'
})
  .then(response => {
    console.log(
      `Response: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`
    );
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(text => console.log(text))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the code will help:

```
// keys
const name = 'something';
const apiKey = 'something';
const apiToken = 'something';

// definition
async function fetchData() {
   try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://api.trello.com/1/boards/?name={${name}}&key=${apiKey}&token=${apiToken}`, {
         method: 'POST'
      });
      console.log(`Response: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
      const data = await response.text();
      console.log(data);
   } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
   }
}

// call the function
fetchData();
```

But, also you can check the following link to understand the reason we use callbacks:

- [JavaScript Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)
- [Asynchronous JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous)
- [Callback functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function),
- [Promise object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).